# DirectionalViewPager swipe horizontal and vertical without selection

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture

I am using DirectionalViewPager [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) for horizontal and vertical swiping, in this library we have to select option(horizontal or vertical) for swiping direction. I want to implement swiping action without selection. For this I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures), but didn't get the What I need. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: check this link might help: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/11/appium-how-to-swipe-vertical-and.html